# Hibernate refresh after merge in single transaction getting old value

Tags: hibernate

Testing things with Hibernate and getting misunderstandings while using session.refresh() after merge()
My simplified entity:

```
@Entity
@Table("Note")
public class Note {

  @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
  private String description;
}
```

I am playing around merge and refresh in single transaction:

```
@Transactional
public void mergeRefresh() {
  Note initialNote = new InitialNote("Initial Description");
  session.persist(initialNode);

  initialNote = initialNote.merge("Second Initial Description");
  boolean isDescriptionMerged = initialNote.getDescription().equals("Second Initial Description"); // TRUE

  session.refresh(initialNote);
  boolean isDescriptionRefreshed = initialNote.getDescription().equals("Second Initial Description"); // FALSE

}
```

Can someone tell me if it is the correct behavior?

Comment: you read back data from the data source before commit was executed.

Comment: @p3consulting But I don't have data yet in the data source and this entity is persistent in context. I noticed this while debugging that after merge() map in a context which holding this object updating only 'key' and in ManagedEntity updating only Instance, but EntityEntry stays initial as before merge()